# Using st_union for joining overlapped areas in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, sql

I have two land use maps for London which have an overlapped area.

Can I use the st_union function in postgis to join them together?

[image: It looks like this from QGIS.]

The attribute table contains information includes legends and building heights.

[image: The attribute table contains the same information for these two maps]

Will this method affect my features?

For example, in the overlapped area, will the build heights become 2 times of the original?

Data from postgres have the same columns and same type of data.

[image: both data are displayed in the postgres with attributes like this]

---

After using @CL.'s method, I got this map. Only some features near the boundaries were deleted which needed to be fixed.

[image: Joint boundaries of two maps.]

Comment: ST_Union affects only the geometry value; the other values do whatever you have specified in the SQL query. Anyway, do the objects in the two tables actually overlap? Are the geometries identical? Do the columns always have identical values? Is there some column that identifies them? Show some example data from both, and what the result should be.

Comment: Yes, the objects are overlapped. I was doing buffer and intersects and the results were larger than I expected. Then I came back and had a look then found out the overlapped.  I will take some pictures from postgres. The result should be for each geom have one idential legend and building height values. thanks

Comment: You answered only two of my four questions.

Comment: Geometries are identical, and geometries columns have identical values. Other columns have repeat values.

Comment: So you have identical rows? Don't you just want to throw the duplicate rows away?

Comment: I think the rows can be identified by the geom. I only want to keep the record appear once.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. Two maps are from same source. As the original whole map of London is so huge. So they divided into parts. I now want to combine two parts into one, I want the result include all information from two maps with features in overlapped areas only appear once. Thanks

Comment: So I ask again: If one of any two overlapping rows are thrown away, is what remains what you want? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: Yes, the remain is what I want.

Comment: And the same rows have the same `mm_id` values?

Comment: Do you want a new table, or append one table to the other?

Comment: I will not keep the mm_id values. I want a new table so that I can have a check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether there are any overlapping objects, use ST_Intersects:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 AS

SELECT *
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Table1
                  WHERE ST_Intersects(Table1.geom, Table2.geom));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It works well on my case. Only some features near the boundary of the two maps were deleted which I need to fix.

Comment: What happens when you exchange `Table1` and `Table2`? If there is no difference, try adding `AND NOT ST_Touches(...)`.

Comment: I think some features partially intersect each other.

Comment: Hello @CL., still wondering why would the exchange make such big differences? thanks

Comment: It appears only the objects in the bottom table were clipped at the line.

Comment: Hello @CL., thanks for your help, I now have successfully solved the problem. Just like what I said, the map was divided into several tiles as it is a very detailed map which have huge size. As you know the overpped area have two boundireds: up and bottom.  I my case, I found that one boundry was cut by a line. So that features were divided neatly by a line. That is the reason, after changing the order there was no gaps left. It is because the people who made the map left the neat line for us to put them together. Thank you very much for your kindly help.